# OpenCV Label connected and Compute feature measurements for image regions

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, label, regions

I need help related to following matlab code

[labelMap_1,num] = bwlabel(labelMap == 1);

labelMap1Stat = imfeature(labelMap_1,'Area','Centroid');

Inside opencv i found few threads that i must use bloblib for it.

But  suppose if i dont want to use it for the sake of code because i need to port this code into android and i am concern about the size. How can i achieve the same thing without using blob library overhead.

If there is no solution then what are the methods inside bloblib that will produce the same result as these two functions??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using functions related to contours like [cvFindContours()](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#cvFindContours) .

[This](http://areshopencv.blogspot.in/2011/09/blobs-with-opencv-internal-function.html) article provides some insights on how to use opencv for blobs.

You can calculate centroid information my using [cvMoments()](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-pub/oleykin/website/OpenCVHelp/ref/OpenCVRef_Cv.htm#decl_cvMoments) function.
Then the center of mass is given by yc = M01 / M00, where M01 and M00 are fields in the structure returned by the Moments call.

Use [cvContourArea()](http://www710.univ-lyon1.fr/~bouakaz/OpenCV-0.9.5/docs/ref/OpenCVRef_StructAnalysis.htm#decl_cvContourArea) to find area.

Comment: can you tell me how can i get the value e.g. in Matlab we does this  
imfeature(labelMap_1,'Area','Centroid') ...should i just divide rows and coloumns by 2 for the the center?

Comment: please tell what is the end result you require. (i dont know what imfeature does)

Comment: here is the detail of the function using center 
http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/images/imfeature.html i need to measure the image region and produce same computation